# How to use Android Tablet as a display for Raspberry Pi 2 running ubuntu mate 15.10

Tags: display, android, raspberrypi

I'm using ubuntu mate for Raspberry Pi 2 on my RPI 2. I want to know that how I can use my Android Tablet running Android 5.0 (Asus Fonepad ME175CG) as a Monitor/Display for my Raspberry Pi 2. I don't want to use Internet for display connection but I want to use a WiFi dongle.

Every time when I start Raspberry Pi 2, it should automatically give display to my Android Tablet via WiFi without any initial settings. Please tell me the way to do this. However I've tried tightvncserver on Raspbian for the same. But I want to do something different.

Comment: What you are asking here is somewhat of a hardware issue, and not having to deal with Ubuntu. You could format a customized monitor, and trick Ubuntu into thinking that sending things over wifi was a monitor. I don't know how to do this, but others may.

Comment: Yes I want to know about how to make ubuntu mate for Raspberry Pi 2 to send display via WiFi to a Android Tablet. Like in Raspbian OS we tight VNC Server for the same & a simple VNC app in Android like VNC Viewer. However there is no hardware issue. I want to know about the method to do the same in ubuntu. I don't want to use tight VNC server, I want to know some other method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android app Xserver XSDL, which you can install on your Android device from Play Store.

There are plenty of videos and other stuff on exactly how to set it up and run it, which is pretty easy.

It works very well and I was using cheap tablets as a touchscreen display for the Pi before the 7" dedicated Pi came along.

Using an X-server app on Android is much much more efficient than using VNC, since the graphic processing is done on the Android device - and not just duplicating the display that the Pi is also driving.

Comment: I tried tightvncserver on ubuntumate 15.10 for pi 2 & set up a VNC server. I've iball data card with Wi-Fi & tried to access VNC server using from my Android Tablet but I was unable to find any Wi-Fi connection as iwconfig on ubuntumate  for pi shows no wireless interfaces. But when I tried same thing on Raspbian OS, it successfully picks up the connection & I was abl. I want to know if I've to set some more configuration on ubuntu mate or I'm doing something wrong to get wireless display on my Android tablet. I used the method given on official website of raspberry pi to make tightvncserver.